# Suggestions on my implementation of Producer Consumer

Tags: java, multithreading

I am naive in multi-threading and is trying to learn it's concepts. This is my implementation for Producer-Consumer problem. Please have a look and suggest me if it is incorrect/crude/any other suggestions that could improve my design.

```
static int data = 0;
static Object obj1 = new Object();

static class Producer implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        produce();
    }

    void produce() {
        while (true) {

                if (data < 5){
                    synchronized(obj1){
                    System.out.println("Producing Data. Now Data is "+data++);
                    obj1.notifyAll();
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else{
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Producer inactive");
                        synchronized(obj1){
                        obj1.wait();
                        }
                        System.out.println("Producer active");
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

        }
    }
}

    static class Consumer implements Runnable{

        public void run(){
            consume();
        }
        void consume() {
            while (true) {

                    if (data > 0){
                        synchronized(obj1){
                        System.out.println("Consuming Data. Now Data is "+data--);
                        obj1.notifyAll();
                        }
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        try {
                            System.out.println("Consumer Inactive");
                            synchronized(obj1){
                            obj1.wait();
                            }
                            System.out.println("Consumer Active");

                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use a `BlockingQueue`.

Comment: What is it that you are producing and consuming? The value of your variable `data`? What is the point of your exercise?

Comment: yes. I just used data variable for the operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok several points.  Producer and Consumer usually share a data structure.  The use of the static data is very odd and quite frankly makes no sense.  Typically what you'll want to share is a data structure like a queue between producer and consumer.  The producer will add things on to the tail of the queue and the consumer(s) will draw things from the head of the queue (FIFO - first in first out).  Right now I see none of that so what exactly is it producing vs consuming?

A good producer consumer architecture doesn't care too much about what type of data is exchanged so you can pass many different types of things over it.  That's where object oriented command architecture will help you out.  In this example SomeMessage represents the root of some object hierarchy so a variety of messages can be exchanged.

Here is a simple example of how you should instantiate a Producer-Consumer architecture in your program:

```
public class SomeClient {
   public void start() {
       Queue sharedQueue = new LinkedList();

       producer = new Producer( sharedQueue );
       consumer = new Consumer( sharedQueue );

       producer.start();
       consumer.start();
   }
}
```

Here is the implementation of that:

```
public class Producer implements Runnable {
    Thread thread;
    Queue queue;

    public Producer(Queue queue) {
       this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void start() {
       thread = new Thread(this);
       thread.start();
    }

    public void shutdown() {
       thread.interrupt(); // request a shutdown
       thread.join();      // make sure we wait until Producer.thread exits before this thread continues
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
           while( !Thread.isInterrupted() ) {
               SomeMessage message = produceAMessage();
               synchronized( queue ) {
                  queue.add( message );
                  queue.notifyAll();
               }
           }
        } catch( InterruptedException ex ) {
           System.out.println("Producer shutting down per request.");
        } finally {
           thread = null;
        }
    }
}

public class Consumer implements Runnable {
    Thread thread;
    Queue queue;

    public Consumer( Queue queue ) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void start() {
        thread = new Thread( this );
        thread.start();
    }

    public void shutdown() {
       thread.interrupt(); // request a shutdown
       thread.join();      // make sure we wait until Consumer.thread exits before this thread continues
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
           while( !thread.isInterrupted() ) {
               SomeMessage message = take();
               doSomethingWithMessage( message );
           }
        } catch( InterruptedException ex ) {
           System.out.println("Stop processing - consumer per request.");
        } finally {
           thread = null;
        }
    }

    private SomeMessage take() throws InterruptedException {
       synchronized( queue ) {
           queue.wait();
           return queue.remove();
       }
    }
}
```

A couple of things that differ in this implementation.  Producer and Consumer share a Queue instance and they use that instance to perform synchronized calls on.  That way neither write or read from that structure without owning the lock.  After they have either added to the queue (producer) or removed from the queue (consumer) they are free from needing to use synchronization.  They are free to process without needing to communicate with each other.  They trade instances of SomeMessage between each instance by adding to the tail and drawing from the head.

The take() method is very important in this code.  Without the helper method you can't process the message AND release the lock.  This important so that your Consumer can receive a message and let go of the lock to allow other Producers/Consumers to add/remove messages while this particular Consumer is processing a message.  This keeps throughput as fast as possible.

And yes I said Producers.  This architecture allows for multiple Producers AND multiple Consumers without needing to change the internals of either Producer or Consumer.

Notice that catching InterruptedException is outside the while loop.  This is very important if you want a predictable program that shuts down cleanly.  An InterruptedException and interrupted concept is the heart of well behaving Java threads.  If you don't know under what conditions this exception is generated you'll never understand multi-threaded apps in Java.  It's not a random occurrence.  Java threads can't be stopped programatically.  Another thread must request it to interrupt itself.  And the thread must obey the request or else it won't stop.  So if we get one.  Shutdown. In this program we'll only get it when we call wait or notify which means while we're processing a message we won't be interrupted.  Consumers will finish processing messages before halting.

Finally, it's actually much easier to implement a Producer-Consumer relationship given the concurrency libraries in Java, but this is a good example of how you do it at the lowest level of Java to understand what those libraries are doing for you.

Comment: As I said, I am pretty naive in this. :) 
As I understood, Producer consumer problem is more about how 2 threads access a data structure. In this case, I am using a scaler data structure - a variable. Producer is incrementing it to a limit of 5 and a consumer is decrementing it to level of 0.

Comment: err no.  A producer-consumer relationship always uses a queue to trade data.  What's important about the p-c relationship is that is scales to many produces and/or consumers to distribute the processing load across many consumers (or producers if need be).  Just trading generic data between two threads doesn't possess that property.  Two threads can trade data using lots of methods: mutex, semaphore, shared memory, message passing, but these aren't p-c relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulating the consume and produce behaviors could be more more reusable. In the code below I decoupled the shared resource synchronization issues from consumer/producer thread which could be useful in solving similar problems like Object Pool and Connection Pool.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class ProducerConsumer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SyncQueue syncQueue = new SyncQueue(1);
        Producer producer = new Producer(syncQueue , 10);
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer(syncQueue,10);

        producer.start();
        consumer.start();
    }

}

class SyncQueue {
    private Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    private Integer size;
    public SyncQueue(Integer size) {
        super();
        this.size = size;
        this.signalledBefore = false;
    }

    public synchronized void put(Integer data){
        while(queue.size() == size){
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        queue.add(data);
        notifyAll();
    }
    public synchronized Integer get(){
        while(queue.isEmpty()){
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Integer data = queue.remove();
        notifyAll();
        return data;
    }
}

class Producer extends Thread{

    private SyncQueue syncQueue;
    private Integer size;
    public Producer(SyncQueue syncQueue, Integer size) {
        this.syncQueue = syncQueue;
        this.size = size;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (Integer i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            syncQueue.put(i);
            System.out.println("Produced:" + i);
            try {
                sleep((int)Math.random()*100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

}

class Consumer extends Thread{

    private SyncQueue syncQueue;
    private Integer size;

    public Consumer(SyncQueue syncQueue, Integer size) {
        this.syncQueue = syncQueue;
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (Integer i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            try {
                sleep((int)Math.random()*100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Consumed:" + syncQueue.get());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your code snippet looks promising, but please say, what is your question, exactly?

Comment: Thanks, I'd like to suggest Bhaskar to use a Queue data structure as the shared resource in consumer/producer problem and to encapsulate synchronization inside that queue.